# Terminal: No Such file directory

Tags: macos, terminal

I'm using macOS El Capitan and I'm trying to get a folder in Terminal.

I tried this: cd {dragged folder into Terminal} but then I get the error "no such file directory".

[image: screenshot]

How can I solve this error?

Comment: You need a space after `cd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a space after `cd` and it will work.